# MVC 4 - Validate only one form with multiple partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, unobtrusive-validation

I'm working on a MVC 4 exercise project where I've multiple partial views and when I submit on one of this the entire page validates. I want that every button validates only their own forms.

The page looks like this:

[image]

This a partial views example:

```
@model Money.Models.Category

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Category", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createCategoryForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Category</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input id="createCategorySubmit" type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And this a part of the entire view:

```
@model Money.Models.Transaction

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Transaction</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "Category")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId)
        </div>

        <div id="createCategory">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_CreateCategory.cshtml")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountId, "Accout")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("AccountId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountId)
        </div>

        <div id="createAccount">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_CreateAccount.cshtml")
        </div>
```

Have you some idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the new content with the validator:

```
$('form').data('validator', null);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
```

Comment: I tried something like this but it doesn't works
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#createCategorySubmit").click(function () {
                $("#createCategoryForm").data('validator', null);
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#createCategoryForm"));
            });
        });